# jQuery and event handlers, why does it matter if I split the selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In jQuery I have experienced a difference in how my event handlers work, depending on whether I split the selector.

Selector not split (#myId .someClass):

```
$('#myId .someClass').on('click', function (e) {
  alert('x');
});
```

Selector "split" (#myId ........ .someClass):

```
$('#myId').on('click', '.someClass', function (e) {
  alert('x');
});
```

When I use the latter, I will get the same event multiple times from same click, whereas the first only give me the click event once (however I sometimes experience that the first one does not even work).

Can someone explain why there is this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is e.g. that the first version

```
$('#myId .someClass').on('click', function (e) { ...
```

binds the click event to all `.someClass` elements that are descendants of the element with the id `#myId` and are already in the DOM when the page is loaded, while the second version

```
$('#myId').on('click', '.someClass', function (e) { ..
```

will delegate the click event from the `#myId` element to all descendant elements with the class `.someClass`, even if they are dynamically added later.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

As one essential quote from there, section "Direct and delegated events":

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().